# tcp connection can still get eagain after receive fin packet?

Tags: go, tcp

this is my code

Firstly I init a tcp server

```
type server struct {
    serverConns chan net.Conn
    addr        string
}

func (s *server) init() error {
    s.serverConns = make(chan net.Conn)

    l, err := net.Listen(network, ":8888")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.addr = l.Addr().String()
    fmt.Println(s.addr)

    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := l.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            s.serverConns <- conn
        }
    }()

    return nil
}
```

Then I create a tcp connection, and close connection from server. CheckConnErr call syscall.Read to read data from connection. In my opinion, after server close connection, client receive fin packet and syscall.read will get EOF. But in this case, syscall.Read get EAGAIN, that means connection is still alive.

```
func TestRemoteEOF(t *testing.T) {
  var s server
  require.Nil(t, s.init())
  
  // dial to server
  var n net.Conn 
  
  // close connection from server 
  serverConn := <-s.serverConns
  require.Nil(t, serverConn.Close())

  buf := make([]byte, 100)
  hit := time.Now()
  err2 := checkConnErr(n, buf)
  require.Equal(t, err2, io.EOF)
}
```

I also check with wireshark, the time of hit is later than fin arrive time, so what is the cause of this phenomenon?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuyX7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT9NO.png)

Comment: AFAIK, EAGAIN does not mean connection is alive. It merely means nothing happened in that call, so you can try again.

Comment: `checkConnErr` is missing, see [mcve].

Comment: Note that EAGAIN == EWOULDBLOCK. Since Go uses non-blocking I/O, it's entirely expected.